# Adding struct pointers to slice of interface pointers

Tags: pointers, go, struct, interface, slice

I have an interface and a struct implementing it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vehicle interface {
    GetColor() string
    SetColor(color string)
}

type Car struct {
    Color string
}

func (car *Car) SetColor(color string) {
    car.Color = color
}

func (car *Car) GetColor() string {
    return car.Color
}

func NewCar(color string) *Car {
    car := new(Car)
    car.Color = color

    return car
}

func main() {
    car := NewCar("red")
    vehicles := make([]Vehicle, 0)
    vehicleSelection := make([]*Vehicle, 0)

    vehicles = append(vehicles, car)
    vehicleSelection = append(vehicleSelection, car) //DOES NOT WORK!

    for _, vehicle := range vehicleSelection {
        vehicle.SetColor("blue") //DOES NOT WORK!
    }

    for _, vehicle := range vehicles {
        fmt.Println(vehicle.GetColor())
    }
}
```

I want to have a subset (`vehicleSelection` slice) of all my vehicles (`vehicles` slice). All changes made to vehicles in the `vehicleSelection`slice must also be reflected by the vehicles in the `vehicles` slice. Therefore I want the `vehicleSelection` slice to be a slice of pointers. How can I add `cars` to this slice?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/9vW_heZgELF if the dynamic type of the interface value is a pointer type you don't need no interface pointer.

Comment: And if the dynamic type is not a pointer then no amount of interface pointers will help, since the methods will not be able the modify the receiver.

Comment: Pointers to interfaces make only sense when you want to *replace* the whole, pointed-to, interface value, if you want to modify the dynamic value inside the interface a pointer to the interface is useless.

Comment: If you still feel like you need pointers to interfaces then you need "pointers to interfaces", that means you need to convert the concrete value to an interface value and then take the pointer of that interface value. Keep in mind that while Go will automatically dereference pointers when calling methods on pointers-to-concrete-types, it will not do so when invoking methods on pointers-to-interfaces, which means you'll have to do the dereferencing yourself. https://play.golang.org/p/Ldw5h9nGAEj

Comment: Thx for your detailed explanations! Helps me a lot!